# Final byte in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to understand a code to an android app.

The code defines a final byte

```
            // defines bsval to be a bytearray which has been received from the remote device
            final byte[] bslval = data1.getByteArray(HRPService.BSL_VALUE);
```

My question is about bslval[0] which occurs in the later part of the code

```
try 
                        {
                            Log.i(TAG, "BYTE BSL VAL =" + bslval[0]);
                            TextView bsltv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BodySensorLocation);
                            bsltv.setText("\t" + mContext.getString(R.string.BodySensorLocation)
                                    + getBodySensorLocation(bslval[0]));
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                        }
```

what is bslval[0] actually ?. The zero byte of bslval ?.

Comment: First byte in `bslval` byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you have to understand is that `[]` signifies array, which means that `bslval` is an array. If you were to write out an array of strings it would look like this;

`["this", "is", "a","string", "array"]`

an array is like a list, and when you write `byte b = bslval[0]`, you are getting the first item of the list, because lists in java start at zero. If you were to write `byte b = bslval[1]` you would be getting the second byte out of the list.

Because a byte is a small number (126 - -126 I think), your array might look like this;

`[80, 89, 35, 12, 44]`

If that were your array and you wrote `byte b = bslval[3]`, b would equal 12, the fourth byte in the array

Answer (score 2):

`bslval` is an array of bytes. Arrays in Java are indexed from 0 to the lenght-1. So `bslval[0]` is the array value at index 0. It is the first byte in the array.

The `final` means that you cannot change the value of `bslval` to let it point to another array.